# Multiple nest structure for lme()

Tags: r, sas

I want to build a mixed-effects model with multiple nest structure in R. For example, month nested in year, day nested in year and year. Response variable Y is temperature and predictor variable X is time. The following SAS code can give me exactly what I need.

```
proc mixed data=dataset;
 class year month day;
 model Y=X;
 random day(year) month(year) year;
 run;
```

However, when I use lme(), I do not know how to set up this structure. It should be something like

```
fitted.model <- lme(Y~X, random=list(~1|year/day, ~1|year/month, ~1|year), data=dataset)
```

The above command does not work. If I wrote as

```
fitted.model <- lme(Y~X, random=list(~1|year, ~1|month, ~1|day), data=dataset)
```

I will get the nested random effect year/month/day which is what I do not want to have.